# Advanced digitizing not providing horizontal figures

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, vector, cad

I am using QGIS 3.16.3, working in a project EPSG:25832. After enabling a polygon layer and the advanced digitizing, when I add a feature (e.g. a rectangle), at the first click the figure is built referring to an angle that is not horizontal.
The whole rectangle is then correctly built snapping at 90° as requested but it is built not horizontally.

Of course I can rotate the polygon later, or transefer all layers in a new projet, but the project is huge and I am working on it since months. I would like a solution in this project-
[image]

I tried to use the Advanced digitizing tool in a new project EPSG:25832 and it works fine, providing horizontal figures.

Comment: What projection is your polygon layer in?

Comment: The same as the project. I found the solution: the whole project was rotated 5°, accidentally this rotation wass set in the bottom right corner (Coordinate, Scale Magnifier, Rotation...). Solved.